# ListView elements not displaying after scroll on Xamarin Forms (android) app

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.forms

Having the ListView below contaning `Tasks` as elements:

[image: Initial Load]

The buttons change the status of a specific `Task`. So When `Start` button is clicked, the Status changes to `Started`, and normally the `Start` button is hidden manually, and the `Pause` button should be shown instead as below:

[image: Updated view]

Each button has its own click event handler, as the Start below:

```
private async void BtnStartTask_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = (Button)sender;
    if (btn.CommandParameter is TaskViewModel model)
    {
        // Task
        if (model.ModelType == Enums.ModelType.Task.ToString())
        {
            await _api.UpdateStatus(new StatusUpdateDTO
                {ID = model.ID, ModelType = Enums.ModelType.Task.ToString(), StatusID = (int) Enums.TaskStatus.Started});                    
        }
        else// Ticket
        {
            await _api.UpdateStatus(new StatusUpdateDTO
                { ID = model.ID, ModelType = Enums.ModelType.Ticket.ToString(), StatusID = (int)Enums.TicketStatus.Assigned });
        }

       UpdateView(Enums.Buttons.Start);
    }
}

private void UpdateView(Enums.Buttons buttonPressed)
{
    switch (buttonPressed)
    {
        case Enums.Buttons.Start:
            // Hide Start
            BtnStartTask.IsEnabled = false;
                BtnStartTask.IsVisible = false;

            // Show Pause
            BtnPauseTask.IsEnabled = true;
            BtnPauseTask.IsVisible = true;

            // Enable End
            BtnEndTask.IsEnabled = true;
            BtnEndTask.IsVisible = true;

            BVStarted.IsVisible = true;
            BVFinished.IsVisible = false;
            BVInitial.IsVisible = false;
            BVPaused.IsVisible = false;
            break;
        case Enums.Buttons.Pause:
            // Hide Pause
            BtnPauseTask.IsEnabled = false;
            BtnPauseTask.IsVisible = false;

            // Show Start
            BtnStartTask.IsEnabled = true;
            BtnStartTask.IsVisible = true;

            BtnEndTask.IsEnabled = true;
            BtnEndTask.IsVisible = true;

            BVStarted.IsVisible = false;
            BVFinished.IsVisible = false;
            BVInitial.IsVisible = false;
            BVPaused.IsVisible = true;
            break;

        case Enums.Buttons.End:

            BtnPauseTask.IsEnabled = false;
            BtnPauseTask.IsVisible = true;

            BtnStartTask.IsEnabled = false;
            BtnStartTask.IsVisible = false;

            BtnEndTask.IsEnabled = false;
            BtnEndTask.IsVisible = true;

            BVStarted.IsVisible = false;
            BVFinished.IsVisible = true;
            BVInitial.IsVisible = false;
            BVPaused.IsVisible = false;
            break;                 
    }
```

The problem arises, when the ListView is long enough to require scrolling.
If i try clicking the buttons, on an element of the ListView that is loaded after scrolling, the respective buttons don't display as below:

[image: Issue]

After this, if I scroll up and down through the elements with the issue, I can later see the changes reflected.

I've tried all the `CachingStrategy` options with no result.

Any idea how to fix this behaviour ?

Comment: Care to show your adapter code?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: as you can see the update of the buttons is manual. I placed only the `Start` button click event handler as the others are the same. The difference is in the button clicked which serves as a parameter for `UpdateView` function.

Comment: There is currently a bug on the latest Xamarin.Forms that causes this. If you downgrade to 3.6 it should go away, not sure when they will release a fix for this. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6830

Comment: @AndresCastro you were right man. The issue is gone with version `3.6.0.344457` of Xamarin Forms. Before I had the latest version `4.1.0...`